# Spring Rest template overwriting Authorization header value

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-web

I am making rest call like below:

```
REST_TEMPLATE.exchange(
        external_rest_url,
        HttpMethod.POST,
        new HttpEntity<>(dto, getHeaders()),
        Map.class)
```

and my headers are as below:

```
private HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set("User-Agent","Spring's RestTemplate");
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "some value");
    return headers;
}
```

when I run my code the header `HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION` is getting replaced with undefined

See request header in snapshot below from network logs:
[image]

Do anyone know why spring is behaving like this or specifically `spring-web:5.0.5` jar. I tried changing the version of jar as well but result is same.

Springboot version I use is `2.0.x`.

Comment: User-Agent is different too no,

Comment: Yeah! you are right. I don't know why it's set differently when I had set it to something else

Comment: What if you try to set Authorization header value to proper syntax - Authorization:<type> <credentials> ? For example : Authorization: Basic YWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuc2VzYW1l

Comment: I tried putting SSWS credentials which is similar to basic auth i.e. Authorization: SSWS YWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuc2VzYW1l

Comment: you are mixing things. resttemplate is used to send http request to another server from your application. the screenshot shows that you are sending the request to server (may be your server) which is handled by @RequestMapping method

Comment: No I am not mixing things. I am sending request to third party rest server

Comment: How is the request in your browser related to the thing you do on the server. You are comparing different things. You are looking at the request from the browser to your server NOT the request from the server to the other server.

Comment: Gotcha. It makes sense. Can you please put same as answer with some elaboration.

Answer (score 3):

you can add an interceptor to your RestTemplate if you need to add the same headers to all requests:

```
public void sampleHeader(final RestTemplate restTemplate){
    //Add a ClientHttpRequestInterceptor to the RestTemplate
    restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new ClientHttpRequestInterceptor(){
        @Override
        public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
            request.getHeaders().set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "some value");//Set the header for each request
            return execution.execute(request, body);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the header is getting overwritten just like in my case.